# Different actions for each card with jQuery in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want each card of [this plugin](http://www.davidbo.dreamhosters.com/?page_id=11) to take the user to some specific page so I tried the following code which works fine:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.fc_card-container', function() {
    alert('clicked!');
    location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

However, I have 10 cards (`.fc_card-container`) and I am supposed to set a different destination page for each one. How can I do that?

UPDATE:
Someone told me to do the following, but the extra data-url property disappears.. :(

> On each `fc_card-container` element you could add an extra `data-*`
>   property to store the URL that the click event should go to, something
>   like this:
>
> ```
> <div class="fc_card fc_auto fc_flipping-right" data-url="http://stackoverflow.com" data-direction="right"
> ```
>
> data-autoflip="2000" data-start="1000">
>
> ```js
> jQuery(document).on('click', '.fc_card-container', function() {
>     window.location.assign($(this).data('url'));
> });
> ```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get all DOM nodes with `.fc_card-container` class and the `data-url` attribute is being used in a DOM element without that class:

`<div class="fc_card fc_auto fc_flipping-right" data-url="http://stackoverflow.com" data-direction="right"`

So, either add the required class or change the `data-url` attribute to the correct DOM node.

Comment: is there an alternative way to do it without adding the data-url attribute ? because since its a plugin I think I can't do it. I only add each card by a wordpress shortcode.

Comment: You need to find a way to tell each card where it should link to.

Since it's a Wordpress plugin, either ask the developer for that option or show us the code to check if there is any flag to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".fc_card-container .fc_card" ).each(function(index) {
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            window.location.assign($(this).data('url'));
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

You can also use
$( ".fc_card-container > div" ).each(function(index)